# Sub menu closing too fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

The sub menu of a Wordpress site I'm working on closees so fast. But on some users browsers all is fine. The problem is obvious on my part when I go to services -> pets, I can't click anything

http://www.jokerleb.com

The css of the menu

```
.header_menu_res ul,
.header_menu_res ul ul,
.header_menu_res ul ul ul {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.header_menu_res ul li.first {
    padding-left: 0;
    background: none;
}

.header_top .header_top_res p a{
    color: #FDC300 !important;
}

/*menu font color*/
.header_menu_res ul li a {
    color: #FDC300;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

.header_menu_res ul {
    z-index: 99;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 1;
}

.header_menu_res ul a {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: relative;
    color: #555;
    z-index: 100;
    display: block;
    line-height: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.header_menu_res ul li:hover a {
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.header_menu_res ul li.current_page_item,
.header_menu_res ul li.current-menu-item,
.header_menu_res ul li.current-menu-parent a {
    color: #555;
    background: #f4f4f4;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.header_menu_res ul li li.current_page_item,
.header_menu_res ul li li.current-menu-item {
    background: none;
}

.header_menu_res ul li.current_page_item a,
.header_menu_res ul li.current-menu-item a {
    color: #555;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.header_menu_res ul.children li a {
    background: #fff;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
}

.header_menu_res ul li {
    float: left;
/
    font: normal 14px/1.2em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    z-index: 999;
     margin: 0 0 20px;
    width: 25%;
}


.menu-item i._mi, .menu-item img._mi {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.menu-item span {
    margin-top: 8px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 60px;
}

.header_menu_res ul li ul {
    margin-top: -2px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
    width: 180px;
    border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0;
    z-index: 998;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 3px;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 3px;
}

.header_menu_res ul.menu ul {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-top: none;
    z-index: 998;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #b7b7b7;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #b7b7b7;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #b7b7b7;
}

.header_menu_res ul.menu ul ul.children {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-top: none;
    z-index: 998;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #b7b7b7;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #b7b7b7;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #b7b7b7;
}

.header_menu_res ul.menu li ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
}

.header_menu_res ul.menu li ul li a {
    background: none;
    padding: 7px 12px;
    width: 156px;
    color: #555;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

.header_menu_res ul.menu li ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.header_menu_res ul.menu li ul ul {
    margin: -32px 0 0 181px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 3px;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 3px;
}

.header_menu_res ul.menu ul.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin: -2px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 3px;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 3px;
}

.header_menu_res ul.menu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display: block;
}

.header_menu_res ul.menu ul.sub-menu li ul.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    top: 2px;
    left: 180px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

.header_menu_res ul.menu ul.sub-menu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display: block;
}

.header_menu_res ul li:hover,
.header_menu_res ul li.hover {
    position: static;
    color: #555555;
}

.header_menu_res ul li:hover ul ul,
.header_menu_res ul li:hover ul ul ul,
.header_menu_res ul li:hover ul ul ul ul {
    left: -999em;
}

.header_menu_res ul li:hover ul,
.header_menu_res ul li li:hover ul,
.header_menu_res ul li li li:hover ul,
.header_menu_res ul li li li li:hover ul {
    left: auto;
}

.header_menu_res ul li img.dropdown {
    padding: 2px 0 2px 8px;
    border: none;
}

.header_menu_res ul.sub-menu {
    width: auto;
}

.header_menu_res ul.sub-menu li {
    clear: left;
    margin: 8px 4px 0;
}
/* category menu */

div#adv_categories,
.header_menu_res ul.sub-menu {
    margin: -2px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 8px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-top: none;
    z-index: 998;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

div#adv_categories {
    display: none;
    padding: 0 5px 8px;
}

#menu-header li:hover #adv_categories,
.header_menu .menu li:hover #adv_categories {
    display: block;
}
```

Since Wordpress generates way too much css and I'm sure where's the problem since some people say all is fine; I tried the jquery snippet from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910239/the-content-of-my-dropdown-menu-is-closing-too-fast) but still doesn't work, I tried with different id's and classes. Perhaps I'm targeting the wrong class. The original snippet from the other question

```
$('.main_navigation a').bind('mouseout', function()
{
    var menu = this;
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        $(menu).parents('li').children('ul').hide();
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Please define speed for `hide()` and `show()`

```
$(selector).hide(speed,callback);

$(selector).show(speed,callback);
```

Try below code jquery:

```
$('.main_navigation a').bind('mouseout', function()
{
    var menu = this;
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        $(menu).parents('li').children('ul').hide(500);
    }, 1000);
});
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Comment: This should indeed work, to add to it though, you might want to consider jQuery's .fadeIn() and .fadeOut(). Works the same way but is different appearance wise.

Comment: `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`  is different from `hide()` and `show()`. Alse when you check in inspect element, css is also different.

Comment: Well, they're different, Yeah. Because they DO different things. However, for somewhat smoother transitions, I'd probably myself run a hide() at the start of my JS document, and on mousein/mouseout use fadeIn and fadeOut. Like I said, just an idea though.

Comment: I tried applying it to `.menu a` and `.header_menu a` doesn't work, maybe i should not put a link so that I could click it, will try that and will see how it goes